# What is the use of @JsonIgnore and @Xmltransient?

Tags: json, jackson, jaxb

```
@JsonIgnore 
@Xmltransient
private int id
```

I want to understand the purpose of using these two annotations on top of the some property/field `@JsonIgnore` & `@Xmltransient` with some example.

I already gone through different websites.

Comment: When you went through different websites what did you find?

Comment: So what do you do not understand from http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html and https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html ?

Answer (score 11):

- `@XmlTransient` is a JAXB annotation that signals marshallers to ignore a field/property.
- `@JsonIgnore` is a proprietary Jackson annotation that signals Jackson to ignore a field/property.

Since the question asks about `@JsonIgnore` I'm assuming you're looking for how these are both used by [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Which annotation to use depends on which [`AnnotationIntrospector`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/AnnotationIntrospector) you use with your ObjectMapper.

- `@XmlTransient` is read by the [`JaxbAnnotationIntrospector`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/blob/2.11/jaxb/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java) which attempts to honor JAXB annotations during marshalling to json.
- `@JsonIgnore` is read by the [`JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.11/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java) which reads standard Jackson annotations for marshalling.

**Example without `@XmlTransient`:**

```
public class User
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }
    public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }

    public String getUserName()
    {
        return firstName + "_" + lastName;
    }
}
```

Sample Jackson output:

```
{
    firstName: "Jay", 
    lastName: "Unit", 
    userName: "Jay_Unit"
}
```

Jackson recognizes `userName` as a property because `getUserName()` looks like a field accessor. In this case, `getUserName()` contains the business logic for constructing the userName property and including this in the resulting json may be desired. However, if you don't need the userName property or if the json will be unmarshalled back into the `User` class, sending `userName` over the wire is a waste. You can prevent Jackson from marshalling the field by using @XmlTransient or @JsonIgnore.

**Example with `@XmlTransient` on property:**

```
public class User
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }
    public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }

    @XmlTransient
    public String getUserName()
    {
        return firstName + "_" + lastName;
    }
}
```

Sample Jackson output:

```
{
    firstName: "Jay", 
    lastName: "Unit"
}
```

**Example with `@JsonIgnore` on fields:**

```
public class User
{
    @JsonIgnore
    private String firstName;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }
    public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }

    public String getUserName()
    {
        return firstName + "_" + lastName;
    }
}
```

Sample Jackson output:

```
{
    userName: "Jay_Unit" 
}
```